# MongoDB C# Driver - Return last modified rows only

Tags: c#, mongodb

The data:
The collection contains a list of audit records and I want to return the last modified items from the collection.

For example:

[image: Audit Records]

So the query needs to return Audit 1235 and 1237 Only.

The following statement works in Mongo Shell and returns the data sub-millisecond, I just need to also figure out how to return the entire Collection item instead of just the Id.

```
db.Forms.aggregate(
{ $group: { _id: "$Id", lastModifiedId: { $last: "$_id" } } }
)
```

However, I need to convert this to the C# Driver's syntax.

I have the following at the moment but it's not working and returns (for lack of a better term) weird data (see screencap under the statement).

```
var results = collection.Aggregate()
.Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$Id" }, { "lastModifiedId", new BsonDocument("$last", "_id") } })
.ToListAsync().Result.ToList();
```

[image: Results]

My current solution gets the full collection back and then runs it through an extension method to get the latest records (where list is the full collection):

```
var lastModifiedOnlyList =
from listItem in list.OrderByDescending(_ => _.AuditId)
group listItem by listItem.Id into grp
select grp.OrderByDescending(listItem => listItem.AuditId)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

While this code works, it is EXTREMELY slow because of the sheer amount of data that is being returned from the collection, so I need to do the grouping on the list as part of the collection get/find.

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

**Update:** With Axel's help I managed to get it resolved:

```
var pipeline = new[] { new BsonDocument { { "$group", new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$Id" }, { "LastAuditId", new BsonDocument { { "$last", "$_id" } } } } } } };
var lastAuditIds = collection.Aggregate<Audit>(pipeline).ToListAsync().Result.ToList().Select(_=>_.LastAuditId);
```

I moved that to it's own method and then use the IDs to get the collection items back, with my projection working as well:

```
var forLastAuditIds = ForLastAuditIds(collection);

var limitedList = (
                projection != null
                    ? collection.Find(forLastAuditIds & filter, new FindOptions()).Project(projection)
                    : collection.Find(forLastAuditIds & filter, new FindOptions())
            ).ToListAsync().Result.ToList();
```

"filter" in this case is either an Expression or a BsonDocument. The performance is great as well - sub-second for the whole thing. Thanks for the help, Axel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing an extra OrderBy, this should do:

```
var lastModifiedOnlyList =
from listItem in list
group listItem by listItem.Id into grp
select grp.OrderByDescending(listItem => listItem.AuditId)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

EDIT:

To gain performance in the query, you could use the Aggregate function differently:

```
var match = new BsonDocument
{
    {
        "$group",
        new BsonDocument
            {
                { "_id", "$Id"  },
                { "lastModifiedId", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {
                            "$last", "$_id"
                        }
                    }}
            }
    }
};

var pipeline = new[] { match };
var result = collection.Aggregate(pipeline);
```

That should be the equivalent of your Mongo Shell query.

Comment: Hi Axel, thanks for the info. I've updated my code with your suggestion and while it has improved ever so slightly it still takes quite long, hence the need to move the group by to the Collection get as opposed to the way I'm doing it now. It's not this group by that slows it down, it's the Collection get that's currently taking long to return, i.e

    collection.Find(filter, new FindOptions())

Comment: @JohannMarx I've edited the answer. Please confirm if it works for you.

Comment: Axel, that did the trick, thank you! :) I am now getting the ID and the latest audit ID back (as per the Mongo Shell query), the only thing that I need now is to get the entire Collection item back, i.e. the corresponding Form for that Audit ID.

And it's nice and fast too! :)

Comment: @JohannMarx: That's great. Thanks for letting me know that it worked :) . Could you select my answer as the correct one please? It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: will do, for sure! It does help me to get the ID back for the latest record, any suggestions on how to get the actual Collection Item back instead of just the ID? It's not a problem if it's not possible, I can use that list of Audit ID's to query the collection again and get those items back. Thanks again for your help, appreciate it!

Comment: var query_id = Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse("50ed4e7d5baffd13a44d0153"));
var entity = dbCollection.FindOne(query_id); // Replace the long string with your variable that has the id of the matched element

Comment: Thank you very much Axel, I have the whole thing working now. You're the man!

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)